# How to set different color opacity for first 5 background image then repeat color again?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

I have more than 50 images which I am retrieving from the database and I have five to six colors which I have to set opacity for first 5 background image and after five images color will be repeated.
For example : Colors are `green, red, yellow, blue, orange` now the first image which I am retrieved from the database will be green opacity, the second image will be red opacity, the third image will be yellow opacity, four images will be blue opacity etc.

After 5 background image completing, Color will repeat on next 5 images.

Is it possible? I haven't tried it because I don't have any idea from where I start.

would you help me in this?

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db/connection.php');

/*retrieve image */
$sql_bg="SELECT background_img FROM request";
$sql_bg_result = $conn->query($sql_bg);

?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($sql_bg_result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $sql_bg_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $background_img=$row['background_img'];
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $background_img;?>" width="100%" height="200">
    <?php
    }  
 }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a counter for your loops, and output a class based on the counter for each image...

```
<?php
$c = 0;
if (isset($sql_bg_result->num_rows) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $sql_bg_result->fetch_assoc()) {
$background_img=$row['background_img'];
?>
<img class="Image<?php echo $c;?>" src="images/<?php echo $background_img;?>" width="100%" height="200">
<?php 
 $c++;

  //Reset the counter when you get to 5
  if ($c % 5 == 0) {
    $c = 0;
  }

 }  
}
?>
```

...from there it's just CSS for the five resultant classes:

```
.Image1 {opacity: 0.5}
.Image2 {opacity: 0.6}
```

etc

Comment: Did you really initialized the `$c` as a string? Why?

Comment: Typing too fast haha